# What are some examples of good, free poker tournament software?

Tags: tournament, software

I'm looking for a good and free software that will help me setup a poker tournament structure. 
The idea is to keep simple stats about the game in a screen available for everyone to see during the tournament.

The stats I'd like to see are:

- Current level (BB and ante if any, at this level)
- Time remaining in current level (along with next level info)
- Time remaining until next break
- Size of average stack / number of remaining players
- Number of entries / rebuys / addons
- Prize pool

Comment: good and free ;-) nice combination

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because software suggestions, generally are not good questions as they become dated, and have very little value to future users, and also the answers here are all very spammy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PokerRoom.com has a great one that I have used.

http://www.pokerroom.com/promos/poker-shop/free-stuff/organizer.html

Solid UI and does everything that you have asked for, along with most of it being fully-customizable.

Comment: Site is down now

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a quite Googleable question. From the first page of my search on "online poker timers":

http://www.thatpokerclock.com/free-poker-clock.php <- This was the first couple listed

http://www.pokerdiy.com/poker-blinds-timer.aspx <- This one was further down but it seems to have all the features you want

Comment: Very nice links. +1

Answer (score 2):

PTM is free and easy to use - it's very customisable and PokerDIY can show your league scoreboard too
http://www.pokerdiy.com/poker-blinds-timer.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try Treek's Poker Tournament Director. It has free and pro version. I believe, that features you requested are included in free version of this [poker timer](http://www.treekspoker.net).

Comment: Link seems to no longer be valid. Looks like you might still be able to find the software [here](https://www.jandrozd.eu/products/treeks-poker-tournament-director/) though.

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS use the free version of CasinoWare: https://www.casinoware.net/quick-start/free-download
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I remade the one from pokerroom in Unity, which was my all time favorite: https://grrava.itch.io/hptm

Comment: Can you add screenshots, more details, etc.? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just launched an app on App Store and Google Play called Poker Champion.

Current version support single table home games.
I.e. max 10 players.

Next version will support multi-table, multi-day, multi-flight tournaments.

Please check it out :-)

Comment: your answer is borderline spam, this is a question and answer site, and not a good place to promote your products